# 404 after 43 seconds TTFB

Tags: http-status-code-404, simple-html-dom

I have script which uses simple_html_dom to parse different site data. It looks through my table of users, grabs the various sites needed, and then parses the data and stores them into my db.

The problem is that when I iterate through more than 3 users I get a 404 error. After a lot of debugging (much of which I'm learning as I go) it looks like as soon as my TTFB hits 40 seconds I get a 404 not found error. Anything under that the page returns fine.

I included the following in my php file to extend the time but this problem seems to ignore these statements.

// It may take a whils to crawl a site ...

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
ini_set('max_input_time', -1); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
set_time_limit(0);
```

But I've never had this problem before where I get a 404 for a page that exists. I'm somewhat new to simple_html_dom and crawling through different pages but is the problem that the wait time is too long? If so how do I can I fix that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it did not have to do with execution time or any setting I could change with the php script. For anyone having the same issue this was fixed by changing the way simple_html_dom loads the script from:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url_link);
```

To:

```
$html = @file_get_contents($url_link);
$html = str_get_html($html);
```

Hope this helps someone else!